# DataTables initialization error

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTables in a Project with Angular and Laravel as beckend.

I get this error When I try to attach on click events:

```
DataTables warning: table id=datatables - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.
```

part of the HTML code:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>ID</th>
                                  <th>CODICE</th>
                                  <th>PRODOTTO</th>
                                  <th>PREZZO</th>
                          .....
```

And part of the module.ts where I get the error:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const that = this;

    that.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',

      'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']],
      responsive: true,
      search: '_INPUT_',
      searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
      pageLength: 2,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post<any[]>(
            'api/prodotti/prodotti_executing/',
            dataTablesParameters, {

            }
          ).subscribe(resp => {
            that.prodotti = resp;

            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.length,

              data: []
            });
          });
      },
      //columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }]
    };
  }
ngAfterViewInit() {


    const table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

    // Edit record
    table.on( 'click', '.edit', function () {
        const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        console.log(table);
        const data = table.row($tr).data();
        alert( 'You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.' );
    } );

    // Delete a record
    table.on( 'click', '.remove', function (e: any) {
        const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        table.row($tr).remove().draw();
        e.preventDefault();
    } );
```

How I can get the datatable to set on click events?

Thanks,
Federico

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the documentation to retrieve the datatable instance

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/dt-instance

```
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
//...
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
private datatableElement: DataTableDirective;


ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then(dtInstance =>
   {
      //use dtInstance here
      //...
   });
```

**Note** 
You should not use jquery if you can avoid it in angular projects